# Does Android In-App billing API3 support Android api-version 8?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an in-app billing application and everything is working fine when I'm testing the app on my galaxy s 3.
but when I'm trying to test the app on my galaxy tab which has foryo 2.2 I just got "3" as a response and I don't know what does it mean !

so my question is : 
Does Android In-App billing API3 support Android api-version 8?
if not what is the supported api-version ? is it 16 or higher or what ?

CODE:

Bundle owne

```
dItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
```

the response for api-version 16 is 0 which means successful connection 
on android api-version 8 or 9 gives me 3 ! which means there is a failure somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated the Google Play app on your Galaxy Tab? I'm pretty sure it requires an update to the app for the "new" API to be usable.

A response code [with the value 3 indicates that](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) "Billing API version is not supported for the type requested".

Comment: everything is updated ! 
@Avadhani is it a relation between the android version and the API3?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the response codes for InApp Billing requests [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#billing-codes).  As you are getting 3 as a response code,Billing `API` version is not supported for the type requested.